# How to know when I disconnected from a Linux Server

Tags: linux

This is an output message on the Linux terminal.

```
$ client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is asking about.  Is it asking about what the message means (the SSH connection was interrupted), or about what produces it (your SSH client)? Or does it ask about _being notified_ when this happens ("How to know when...")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login again and exec `last el` (where `el` is your username)

This will generate output like:

```
$ last romeo
romeo    pts/0        192.168.0.51     Tue Nov 22 10:09   still logged in
romeo    pts/0        192.168.0.51     Mon Nov 21 13:10 - 13:17  (00:07)
romeo    pts/0        192.168.0.51     Sat Nov 19 07:03 - 07:07  (00:03)
romeo    pts/0        192.168.0.51     Fri Nov 18 19:43 - 19:43  (00:00)
romeo    pts/0        192.168.0.51     Fri Nov 18 06:46 - crash  (12:56)
romeo    pts/0        192.168.0.51     Thu Nov 17 20:14 - 20:21  (00:07)
```

Check the second line (here it said **Mon Nov 21 13:17** is the last logout)